# Should we reword a question's title so that it can get more Google visitors?

Tags: discussion

I am referring to my question [here](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/4720/is-a-complete-global-flood-physically-possible).

Currently the title is "**Is a complete global flood physically possible?**" It's a much more accurate and scientific-oriented title compared to my initial title "**Did God have enough water to flood the earth during Noah's time**"?

But I think that my original title is more SEO friendly than the current one. So, should I change the title back, so that we can hope to capture more visitors from Google?

Comment: relevant: http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/1428/religious-questions

Comment: Additionally, with 330 views in 16hours, by this site standards, your question is doing fine already.

Comment: @plannapus, aim higher! Let's see how much Google visitors we can draw in 6 months to 2 years time, _that_ is our target.

Answer (score 5):

Putting aside the fact that even with the new title a google search on the plausibility of the deluge myth is in my opinion as likely to show your question as with the other title, you have to consider that, yes we want to attract more people, but considering how touchy most aspects of Earth Sciences are to certain people (think about climate sciences, evolution, age and history of the earth, non-renewable resources, ... hell, even "shape" of the earth is somehow touchy for some people), we have reasons to be very careful as to what kind of people we want to attract here, and what kind a debate we want to start.

Additionally I think your original title invites more a debunking of the myth while the second one invites more a thought experiment. In the first case it would have been more on-topic on Skeptics while in the second case it is definitely well-suited for our site and even (judging by the answers you got) frankly interesting.

Answer (score 5):

Question titles should accurately reflect the content of a post rather than serve as clickbait seo fodder.  Your original title:

> Did God have enough water to flood the earth during Noah's time

is not well suited to this site.  This suggests a question about a deity and whether that deity is capable of conjuring sufficient water to flood the earth.  A question about this particular god and their powers would be suited to one of the religious stacks or on the Skeptics stack.

However, if your intent was to validate or refute the flood story (which is shared among many people and not unique to one religion) you could instead ask about geologic evidence of floods and theories that explain great regional flooding that became global floods in myth.  This wouldn't be a question about a god though, but geologic record and interpretations of that record.

The current title,

> Is a complete global flood physically possible?

is better suited to this site.